# migrating from directx 9 to directx 10

Tags: c++, directx

I have a software using DX9 but it was having too many issues with fps drop on specific windows 10 versions, so i tried to compile it using the d3dx10 lib and received the following errors:

[image]

I don't know if it will be easy like that, but there's any way to reimplement these functions using the new ones on directx10? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should link to ``d3d9.lib`` and ``D3dx9.lib`` cause those are Direct3D 9 and extension APIs

Comment: BTW, just linking to Direct3D 10 static libraries won't force your app to use Direct3D 10 APIs. You will have to rewrite your code using Direct3D 10 APIs. Anyways, Direct3D 9/10 are both legacy APIs so I wouldn't recommend using them.

Comment: I understand... The problem is, this code is from a game super big, based on directx, but as they're using dx9 people are getting fps issues while playing on windows 10 update creators, do you know if there's a way to fix that? when i change the flag to hardware vertex, it fix the fps drop but we can't see the game models anymore

Comment: You should def use hardware vertex processing rather than using software vertex processing to improve performance. Since you are using Direct3D 9, use PIX to debug pixel shader, it's bundled with June 2010 SDK. Not sure, if Visual Studio 2013 and above supports debugging older versions of shader

Comment: Im using visual studio 2005. When i enable hardware, the character disappear, i can still move, but the models bugs a lot

Comment: Then start debugging vertex and pixel shaders using PIX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's going to be quite a project to jump 14+ years ahead in a single port, but there a lot of resources available to help.

Firstly, there is an official guide for moving from [Direct3D 9 to Direct3D 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205073.aspx). These days you should not actually port to Direct3D 10 but port to Direct3D 11 which has the same features but broader hardware support, more utility libraries, and more community support. As noted in the official guide [Migrating to Direct3D 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476190.aspx), moving from Direct3D 10 to Direct3D 11 is a pretty straight-forward process. You can logically move code from Direct3D 9 to Direct3D 10 then Direct3D 10 to Direct3D 11 by following both guides at once.

Second, `D3DX`, `D3DX10`, and `D3DX11` are all deprecated as is the legacy DirectX SDK itself. As such, you should take a bit of time to read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx), [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/), and [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/) to be fully up on what's changed here. As you migrate to Direct3D 11, you should work on removing as many dependencies on the legacy DirectX SDK you can.

Third, from the missing exports you are using the `FX` system for your shaders. There is an [Effects for Direct3D 11](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/10/23/effects-for-direct3d-11-update/) but it's not part of `D3DX11`. The latest runtime is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11/wiki). It's important to note that the compiler support for the `fx_4_0`, `fx_4_1`, and `fx_5_0` profiles are **deprecated**, so you should consider moving away from using `FX` to managing your shader and state combinations directly.

> More resources on the retired legacy DirectX SDK: [DirectX SDK Tools Catalog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/10/28/directx-sdk-tools-catalog/), [DirectX SDK Samples Catalog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog/), [DirectX SDKs of a certain age](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/08/21/directx-sdks-of-a-certain-age/), and [The Zombie DirectX SDK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/03/23/the-zombie-directx-sdk/)
>
> More resources for learning Direct3D11: [Getting Started with Direct3D 11](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2011/07/11/getting-started-with-direct3d-11/) and [DirectX Tool Kit for DX11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/)

Note: You should also consider moving to VS 2017 instead of sticking with a 12+ year old toolset. Be sure to check out the [community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) and [this porting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/visual-cpp-change-history-2003-2015).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Well, i think i found the problem debugging the shader, now i need to check if it works in other computers. Also about the vs2017, i plan to upgrade as soon as possible ^^

Comment: Well but I have a book written in d3d9 and I cannot find microsoft documentation helpful at all, for example what should i replace the old enumerations like  D3DDEVTYPE,D3DFORMAT. what happened to them how to replace them in my code, I know they removed it but what should i do now

Comment: For ``D3DDEVTYPE`` see the [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/). For ``D3DFORMAT``, see [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d10/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-d3d9-to-d3d10-considerations#mapping-texture-formats).